# Whatever I try cors just doesn't seem to work in production

Tags: node.js, cors

Hi im using the cors npm library to connect a backend with a front-end ive built backends before with fastApi middleware and that worked perfectly fine but with expressjs it doesn't seem to work in production at all only in development. I keep getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://invoiceappnodejs.herokuapp.com/send_mail' from origin
'https://www.omillerwieldinginvoice.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

here is the code

```
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();



app.use(express.json());
app.options('/send_mail', cors())
app.use(cors({
    allowedHeaders:["*"],
    exposedHeaders: ['*']
    origins:'https://www.omillerwieldinginvoice.com/',
    headers:'*',
    preflightContinue: false,
    methods:"GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE"
}))
```

Comment: "*it doesn't seem to work*" isn't a particularly descriptive problem statement. Can you elaborate? What did you expect to happen? What happens instead? What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck? See [ask]

Comment: `origins` is not a property of the CORS options object; you want to use [`origin`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options) (singular). Also, `https://www.omillerwieldinginvoice.com/` is _not_ a [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin); drop that trailing slash.

Comment: even with origin:"*" it still fails, ive added all of your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Since you explicitly put `https://www.omillerwieldinginvoice.com/` as origin, the request for `https://invoiceappnodejs.herokuapp.com/send_mail` wouldn't work. So you need to add the correct origin to your origins.

Also don't forget to initalize CORS before your routes. So order should be:

```
app.use(cors({});
app.use(express.json());
app.options('/send_mail', cors());
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, I even tried "*" to accept all origins it still hasnt been working for me

Comment: @ToTheStarsInvesting please also share the way you are making the call.

Comment: ok here it is                                                                                                             
      axios
      .post("https://invoiceappnodejs.herokuapp.com/send_mail", mailBody)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ err: true });
      });

Answer (score -1):

Different browser request differently likes: Mozilla: http://www.example.com and chrome: http://example.com. you can use like this:

```
cors({
    origin: ["http://example.com","http://www.example.com"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
})
```